# could someone please look at this? it doesn't seem quite right

Tags: support

[Comment to check](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767862/do-these-hardware-specs-support-linux-working-system#comment1465413_767872)

Not spelling out details for obvious safety reasons

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for calling out the inappropriate comment! Those comments have been removed. Such comments are not welcome here at U&L.

Flagging the comment would be slightly better for these situations, as it leaves a "paper" trail (the flags) closer to the actual issue. One of the options there is: "It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.", which I think would have been appropriate. If you're not sure among the comment flag options, you can always choose the "Something else" option and describe the issue in the textbox.

Thank you again for bringing this to the community's attention!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [dedicated way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to solicit those who can actually decide whether things are quite right or not (iow the elected keepers of the [code of conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct#unfriendly-language)) consists in flag-ing the comment (clic on the flag at the immediate left of the comment) labeled *Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator's attention*

---

About the particular ocurrence you mention, I can only observe that the (quite high-rep and respected) contributor who could (rightfully) read some disgraceful personal attack **did not flag that comment himself** and, as part of some following comment, even explains why he did not.

**[EDIT : reading from comments, I am wrong, he had actually reported.]**

My opinion about this particular occurrence then stands in two parts :

- Who would I be as a third party non involved to arbitrarily decide differently ?
- If anyone else flags this comment and this comment is actually removed and since nobody (apart from mods) can tell who is responsible for the flag, wouldn't the original and a-priori sincere intention of the *victim* be somehow betrayed ?

---

On a side note, answers to personal attacks in comments are generally removed together with the inappropriate comment, this incidentally ruining any attempt from the *victim* to handle the situation according to… their own idiom… ;-)
This certainly contributes to stop flame-wars early but this should imho be adjusted when the personally attacked contributor is not known for fueling that sort of things.

Comment: I did flag! I explained *why* I flagged, namely that such behavior can never be acceptable to a community (imagine how that would impress someone with less of a thick skin, maybe even an actually vulnerable person!), but my main worries do revolve around the person behaving that way – that's really not an OK change in state of mind… [for comparison, same person 4 months ago](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/28464/20658).

Comment: @MarcusMüller :  Mybad then. I had not seen the flag colored, indicating that someone had flagged the comment (as I was used to see in other SE_Sites) and inferred that, since you were (kindly) taking care of the obvious offenser wealth you would have wished your comments to remain. After all, that is the principal point of my answer : I trust that kind comments from some known honest & respectful contributor following a personal attack can be much more profitable to the community than the removal of the whole suite of comments.

Comment: you're really flattering me there. I might have been to blunt in the comments I posted (and which are still there)